# 500 - Tuple Index Out of Range - Objective-C/Python

Tags: python, objective-c, iphone, web-services

I have been working on an iOS project and I have come across a very strange problem. When I consume a web service through my iOS app, I get `500 - Tuple Index out of Range exception`. When I try the same service with Rest Client and same arguments, it works fine no matter what. I am really confused on what going wrong here. I have wasted a lot of hours of research and possible outcomes.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
NSString *userAuthURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:STORE_DEALS_URL_STRING, self.request.storeId];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:userAuthURLString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:WEB_SERVICE_KEY_STRING forHTTPHeaderField:@"Key"];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];

NSHTTPURLResponse* response;
NSError* error = nil;

NSData* webData =[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Here is the Python code to receive the request:

```
  @route('/stores/:storeid')

      def stores_details(storeid,mc):        
      result = store_obj.get_all_stores(storeid)   
      return {'status':'Success','data':result}
```

Comment: You should post some code

Comment: Where does Python enter into this? Is the page you're reading written using a Python framework (e.g. Django)?

Comment: You need to provide more info than that. The problem could be in your url string, but we can't see that. The protocol could require a POST rather than a GET, but we don't know anything about the protocol. You are setting a Content-Type header which makes no sense for a GET request.

Comment: Actually, another developer is working on the Python backend, so I might not have that code at the moment.

Comment: @JamesHolderness Yes, actually I had the ContentType send for a wrong reason. That is mistake # 1 for me. It is a get request and it's been checked thoroughly in the Rest Client. I'll post the Python code as soon as I'll get my hands on it.